# How to deserialise this nested json response and save the the array values with multiple Jobjects (in Unity)

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, deserialization

I have little to no experience in JSON and I am stuck with a problem. Any help is appreciated.

I want to access specifically the names' values from the  *additionalInformation* array.

**JSON Response:**

```
    {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "version": 1,
    "jsonData": [
        {
            "additionalInformation": [
                {
                    "id": "XXX94XXXX9xxXx_xxxXXXX",
                    "name": "xxxx xxx x xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "id": "0xXXxcXxv5PQqT$6i2zLgV",
                    "name": "xxx xxxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "id": "11Krt_our2rPCPqJ_2fKZR",
                    "name": "xxx xxxxxxxx xx"
                },
                {
                    "id": "2jYw4IyBP8KuozM_ej7DGf",
                    "name": "xxxxxxx 1"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3B8O805wL1ufabHMz1Je3v",
                    "name": "xxxxxxx 2"
                },
                {
                    "id": "0FVKUYZkvFaxd_OQUiyPBZ",
                    "name": "xxxxxxx"
                },
                {
                    "id": "3O41QFd0573QQvFco5zUUP",
                    "name": "Xxxxxxxxx"
                }
            ],
            "type": 0
        }
    ],
    "errorMessages": [],
    "warningMessages": [],
    "informationMessages": []
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class CFunctions
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }

    public List<PFunctions>[] jsonData { get; set; }

    public List<string> errorMessages { get; set; }

    public List<string> warningMessages { get; set; }

    public List<string> informationMessages { get; set; }

    /*public CFunctions()
    {
        jsonData = new List<PFunctions>();
    }*/
   }
```

```
[Serializable]
public class PFunctions 
{
    public List<PAdditionalInfo>[] additionalInformation { get; set; }

    public int type { get; set; }

    /*public PFunctions()
    {
        additionalInformation = new List<PAdditionalInfo>();
    }*/
}
```

```
[Serializable]
public class PAdditionalInfo 
{
   public  Guid id { get; set; }

   public string name { get; set; }
}
```

**Deserialisation**

```
var request = UnityWebRequest.Get(baseurl);
var operation = request.SendWebRequest();
var jsonResponse = request.downloadHandler.text;
List<CFunctions>[] PFunctionsList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CFunctions>[]>(jsonResponse);
```

**Error:**

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[CFunctions][]' because the type requires a JSON array to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type that can be deserialized from a JSON object.
> JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
> Path 'statusCode', line 1, position 14.
> UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

**What I tried**

The error pertains even when I changed `List<PAdditionalInfo> to List<PAdditionalInfo>[]`

I am not sure how to use `JsonObjectAttribute` and if it is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared an array of `List<T>` in the models, eg `List<PAdditionalInfo>[]`.  The json represents single arrays, not nested.  You can fix that by choosing one or the other (I decided to use `List<>` but array is valid too):

```
public class PFunctions 
{
    public List<PAdditionalInfo> additionalInformation { get; set; }  // removed []
    ...
}

public class CFunctions
{
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
    public int version { get; set; }

    public List<PFunctions> jsonData { get; set; }    // removed []
    ...
}
```

The class you're deserializing to is incorrect.  Deserialize to the correct type (which is `CFunctions` not `List<CFunctions>[]`):

```
CFunctions cFunctions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CFunctions>(json);
```

Answer (score 1):

the most efficient way to get an additional information  is this one line code and you only need one class

```
 List<AdditionalInformation>  additionalInformation = JObject.Parse(json)
["jsonData"][0]["additionalInformation"].ToObject<List<AdditionalInformation>>();
```

class

```
public class AdditionalInformation
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Parsing JSON response directly into type `List<AdditionalInformation>`  gives an error 'Cannot implicitly convert type JObject to type List<AdditionalInformation>. Any way to work around this? I would like less code as well!

Comment: @holouser This code was tested using your json and evertything was working properly. Did you  use my class AdditionalInformation? Or check json one more time. Maybe json you posted is different from the origional one?